# How to join multiple tables in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm facing performance issue while joining below tables. Can some one please suggest how can we join tables with almost 200 fields with good performance. thanks in advance.

note: I'm providing only three fields with four values but in real I have 200 fields (like employee, department, university ..... etcetera) with almost 50 values (for example employee(1-50), department(1-50), university(1-50)).

I have tried by using map but it is hitting performance very badly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the column which you can use to join or what is the key? All those 200 fields can not be a key. From your data i can see may be `id` can be a key to join all of the tables. Can you clearly show, each table structure/data, their unique key and how they are related to other tables uniquely. Join performance can be enhanced but need to understand the data first

Comment: yes, you are right. id and rec_type are keys to join three tables. these two columns are key for all three tables.

Comment: So whats the issue in joining three tables based on id and rec_type? What have you tried?

Comment: I have created intermediate_table by joining all the fields then trying to do column to row transformation using map, 
I'm facing performance issue while using map. Same code is working for 3 to 4 fields but If we have more fields (like more than 10) it is not working, that to I have (key, value) up to 300. I can't post that code here as it is too long.
update the post with what I have tried, please check.